# Is it possible to give multiple input box in prompt alert in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a situation where i am bound to give multiple input box in a prompt box in JavaScript or jQuery, is there any way we can do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define input box :) you cn just display a div?

Comment: are you looking for something like [jquery-ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), especially the modal form [example](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        close: function(event, ui) { 
            // do whatever you need on close
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" id="input2" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot tweak "Prompt box" of browser, however you can use `jquery ui dialog box`

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```